# Replace entire html-body content with data retrieved from some URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider that I get a valid piece of HTML by calling some RESTful service endpoint or URL:

E.g. `http://myserver/myhtml/`

And, I have a simple HTML page:

```
 <html> 
  <body>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I would then like to replace (on load) the entire contents found within `<body></body>`, with the data that I have got from the web-page above.

I am using *jquery*.

**EDIT:**

Thanks all for your feedback, however, there seems to be more to this problem. I am trying to use this mindmap visualisation here https://github.com/kennethkufluk/js-mindmap, see also the demo here: http://kenneth.kufluk.com/google/js-mindmap/

It works by having the data as Lists and ListItems in html. It will then render a mindmap.

The problem is that the answers supplied is interfering with the mindmap loading. Is there an alternative way to dynamically load the body list items, this besides calling `load` (if this is the problem). Have a look at script.js which fires off the mindmap, given this code is there another way, while still allowing the mindmap to load. Thnx!

Comment: In fact, you didn't try anything. Check : http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I think you can only change the body: `document.body.innerHTML = 'your HTML body'`. I tried `document.documentElement.innerHTML = '<html>...'` but it looks like only replace the body too.

Comment: And be aware about cross origin policy : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @sdespont I tried this with <body id=“result”> but it does not work!

Comment: try this: `$('body').load('http://myserver/myhtml/');`

Comment: @Stiger Still, does not work, Just blank!

Comment: It's should work if you load page from same domain, take a look at my fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/3YUCa/`

Comment: Ok thanks, I can now get it to load.. however I have another problem in my specific project. I have posted further details in my question, if you could please help!

Answer (score 1):

This code will replace the content in `<body>` using an AJAX call:

```
$.get("http://myserver/myhtml/").success( function(result){
    $('body').html(result);
}).error(function(result){
    alert("Error!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){
$("body").html("your content goes here");
});
```